# Questions about class structure, inheritance, etc -- Simple Rougelike in JS

Tags: javascript, game

I have built a small roguelike in JS using minimal frameworks (Tho I am using one library for things like FOV, map generation and a few other small things)

This is my first 'real' project that was done by only me without following any real tutorials, and because of this, I'm feeling like a lot of the things i'm doing might not be totally correct, or the best way to accomplish such things.. My biggest fear is picking up bad habits just because they 'work' or it was easy for me to implement but isn't the correct way

I had a lot of questions, and more so wanted general advice about my use of classes, whether I should be more general with them, stuff like that

Currently, I have 3 files, my Game.js which has my game *object* and the initialization stuff, and then I also have a monster.js class, which uses an entity ID in the constructor in order to determine what kind of monster it is, and then act accordingly

And finally, I have a player.js which handles anything player-related, his movements, actions, inventory, etc

I'll include those here

**Game.JS**

```js
//Imports -- All objects from the game
import { Player } from "./objects/player.js";
import { Monster } from "./objects/monster.js";


//ROT.RNG.setSeed();
// Game object which has two functions (init, getDisplay), init creates a display, getDisplay is called to return said display

export const Game = {
  display: null,
  level: 1,
  textDisplay: null,
  scheduler: null,
  notifications: [],
  invSlots: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"],
  digger: null,
  mapGen: null, //used for map generation
  map: {},
  fov: null,
  enemyChar: ["k", "d", "t", "g"],
  enemys: [],
  freeSpace: [],
  items: [ //Starting items pool, things you can randomly spawn with
    { name: "Short Sword", dmg: 2, equipped: false }, // All items are like this, if item is equipped:true, we calc damage for it
    { name: "worn leather leggings", armor: 2, equipped: false, slot: "legs" },
    { name: "worn leather chestpiece", armor: 3, equipped: false, slot: "chest" },
    { name: "worn leather helm", armor: 1, equipped: false, slot: "head" },
    { name: "hand-me-down Mace", dmg: 2, equipped: false, slot: "hand" },
    { name: "broken training Sword", dmg: 1, equipped: false, slot: "hand" },
  ],
  loot: [ //Loot to be dropped by mobs or found in chests
    { name: "golden crown", armor: 2, equipped: false, slot: "head" },
    { name: "leather leggings", armor: 4, equipped: false, slot: "legs" },
    { name: "long sword", dmg: 4, equipped: false, slot: "hand" },
    { name: "leather chestpiece", armor: 5, equipped: false, slot: "chest" },
    { name: "leather helm", armor: 4, equipped: false, slot: "head" },
    { name: "steel chestpiece", armor: 8, equipped: false, slot: "chest" },
    { name: "steel leggings", armor: 6, equipped: false, slot: "legs" },
    { name: "steel mace", dmg: 3, equipped: false, slot: "hand" },
    { name: "emerald ring", armor: 1, equipped: false, slot: "finger" },


  ],
  rooms: null,
  room: null,
  engine: null,
  roomDebug: [],
  //End of variable declaration

  init: function () {
    this.display = new ROT.Display({ fontSize: 18 });
    this.textDisplay = new ROT.Display({ width: 35, height: 20 }); //Dedicated display specifically for text notifications in-game
    this.fov = new ROT.FOV.PreciseShadowcasting(Game.shadowCast);
    this.scheduler = new ROT.Scheduler.Simple();
    this.engine = new ROT.Engine(this.scheduler);
    document.getElementById("gameContainer").appendChild(Game.getDisplay().getContainer()); //Push display to the body of the page
    document.getElementById("gameContainer").appendChild(Game.textDisplay.getContainer());
    levelSpawn();
    Game.createMap();
    Game.spawnEnemies();
    Game.scheduler.add(player, true)
    for (let i = 0; i < Game.enemys.length; i++) {
      Game.scheduler.add(Game.enemys[i], true);
    }
    this.engine.start();
  },//END OF DISPLAY GENERATION



  getDisplay: function () {
    return this.display;
  }, //END OF DISPLAY RETURN FUNCTION



  createMap: function () {
    // debugger;
    //Generate a map for use in this specific dungeon
    this.digger = new ROT.Map.Digger(); //Width x Height

    //Digger callback function
    let diggerCallback = function (x, y, value) {
      if (value) { return; } //Not storing walls?

      let key = x + "," + y;
      Game.freeSpace.push(key);
      this.map[key] = ".";
    }

    this.digger.create(diggerCallback.bind(this));

    //Draw entire map from players point of view
    Game.drawWholeMap();
    Game.drawRooms();
  }, //END OF MAP CREATION



  spawnEnemies: () => { //Random function for generating some enemies
    for (let i = 0; i < Game.enemys.length; i++) {
      console.log("ENEMY ARRAY ", Game.enemys);
      let spawnRoom = Game.rooms[Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(Game.rooms.length))];
      Game.enemys[i].x = spawnRoom.getCenter()[0];
      Game.enemys[i].y = spawnRoom.getCenter()[1];
    }
    Game.spawnLoot();
    Game.spawnStairs();

  }, //END OF Mob spawn logic

  spawnLoot: () => {
    let spawnRoom = Game.rooms[Math.floor(Math.random() * Game.rooms.length)];

    for (let i = 0; i < Game.level * 1.25; i++) {
      let rndx = Math.floor(Math.random() * spawnRoom._x2);
      let rndy = Math.floor(Math.random() * spawnRoom._y2);

      while (rndx < spawnRoom.x1 && rndx > spawnRoom.x2 - 1) {
        rndx = Math.floor(Math.random() * spawnRoom._x2);
      }

      while (rndy < spawnRoom.y1 && rndy > spawnRoom.y2 - 1) {
        rndy = Math.floor(Math.random() * spawnRoom._y2);
      }

      let pos = rndx + "," + rndy;
      Game.map[pos] = "*";


      console.log("ROOMS ARE LIKE SO ", Game.rooms);
    }
  },


  spawnStairs: () => {
    let spawnRoom = Game.rooms[Math.floor(Math.random() * Game.rooms.length)];
    let pos = spawnRoom.getCenter()[0] + "," + spawnRoom.getCenter()[1];

    Game.map[pos] = ">";
    console.log("STAIRS AT ", pos);
    Game.createSpawn();
  }, //End of stair spawning logic



  drawWholeMap: function () {
    Game.display.clear(); //Simulates actual FOV by clearing any non-seen tiles, this can be removed
    Game.fov.compute(player.x, player.y, 10, function (x, y, r, visibility) { //Draw only what is visable

      let pos = x + "," + y;
      let ch = (Game.map[pos]);

      //If the key shows up in enemies
      let bgColor = (Game.map[pos] ? "#d3d3d3" : "#2b2d2f");
      let fgColor = "#FFF" //Set basic fg color to white

      switch (Game.map[pos]) {
        case ">":
          fgColor = "#585858";//Is it stairs? Draw as grey, etc
          break;
        case "*":
          fgColor = "#FF0"
          break;

        case "%":
          fgColor = "#FFF";
          bgColor = "#F00";
          break;

        case ",":
          fgColor = "#F00";
          bgColor = "#d3d3d3";
          break;
      }

      Game.display.draw(x, y, ch, fgColor, bgColor);

      for (let i = 0; i < Game.enemys.length; i++) {
        if (x == Game.enemys[i].x && y == Game.enemys[i].y) {
          console.log("WE SEE THE ENEMY, ")
          Game.display.draw(Game.enemys[i].x, Game.enemys[i].y, Game.enemys[i].sprite, Game.enemys[i].color, bgColor);
        }
      }

    });

    Game.display.draw(player.x, player.y, player.sprite, "#ff0", ""); //Draw player
  }, // END OF MAP GEN


  drawDoor: function (x, y) {
    Game.display.draw(x, y, "+", "red", "");
  }, //END OF DRAW DOORS FUNCTION


  drawRooms: function () { //Function is pretty clear, we're drawing rooms themselves here, and printing to console the room positions
    this.rooms = Game.digger.getRooms();
    for (let i = 0; i < this.rooms.length; i++) {
      this.room = this.rooms[i];
      //this.room.getDoors(this.drawDoor);
    }
  }, //END OF DRAWROOMS FUNCTION



  createSpawn: function () {
    let spawnRoom = this.rooms[Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(this.rooms.length))];
    console.log("Here is where your player will spawn ", spawnRoom.getCenter());
    player.x = spawnRoom.getCenter()[0]; //First value returned
    player.y = spawnRoom.getCenter()[1]; //Second value returned

    console.log("Player position: ", player.x, player.y);
    Game.drawWholeMap();
  }, //END OF SPAWN CREATION


  //We need to rename this to drawInventory, as well as clean up some of the conditionals and the name of the input variables
  informPlayer: (text) => {
    Game.textDisplay.clear(); //Clear the information screen

    if (Array.isArray(text)) { //If the item passed in is an array, it's the players inventory
      for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        let item = text[i];

        Game.textDisplay.drawText(0, 0, "Your Inventory ");
        let string = Game.invSlots[i] + ") " + text[i].name;
        if (text[i].equipped) {
          string += "%b{green} e";
        }
        Game.textDisplay.drawText(0, i + 1, string);
      }
      Game.textDisplay.drawText(0, player.inventory.length + 3, "Press any key to equip or unequip");
      Game.drawStatus();

      //Otherwise, print string as normal
    } else {
      Game.textDisplay.drawText(0, 0, text);
    }
  }, //END OF archaic TEXT/NOTIFY SYSTEM


  shadowCast: (x, y) => { //Function for use in FOV computations
    let pos = x + "," + y;
    switch (Game.map[pos]) {
      case ".":
        return true;

      case ">":
        return true;

      case "*":
        return true;

      case "%":
        return true;

      case ",":
        return true;

      default:
        return false;
    }
  },


  //New and improved messaging function. The idea here is to read off a continual list of information strings. 
  //We will read an array of strings, for each item we will increase Y draw by 1 so that it continues down the screen
  // If we expand Y to the maximum screendepth of displayText.options.height - 1, clear all the notifications but the last
  //We will also have the status of the player drawn in a seperate function
  notify: (text) => {
    Game.textDisplay.clear();
    //Loop through notifications
    for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
      //Display each notification with increasing y
      Game.textDisplay.drawText(0, i, text[i]);
      if (i == Game.textDisplay._options.height - 2) {
        Game.notifications.splice(0, Game.notifications.length - 1);
      }
    }
    Game.drawStatus();
  },

  drawStatus: () => {
    Game.textDisplay.drawText(0, Game.textDisplay._options.height - 1, "Health: %c{green}" + player.health + "%c{white} Damage: %c{red}" + player.dmg + "%c{white} Armor: %c{yellow}" + player.armor);
  },

  resetGame: () => {
    Game.map = {};
    Game.enemys.splice(0, Game.enemys.length);
    Game.engine = null;
    Game.scheduler.clear();
    Game.display.clear();
    let page = document.getElementById("gameContainer");
    page.innerHTML = "";

    Game.init();
  }



} // END OF GAME OBJECT ITSELF


//First-run initialization, create player, add a starter item to his inventory, set it to 'equipped'


// Create player object, give him starting items, set the starting items to 'equipped' and add their values to our own
var player = new Player(0, 0, '\u263A', [Game.items[Math.floor(Math.random() * Game.items.length)]], Game.enemys);
//Set initial inventory
for (let i = 0; i < player.inventory.length; i++) {
  player.inventory[i].equipped = true;
  if (player.inventory[i].dmg) {
    player.dmg += player.inventory[i].dmg;
  }
  if (player.inventory[i].armor) {
    player.armor += player.inventory[i].armor;
  }
}



function levelSpawn() { //TODO: Expand this function into a much more robust version that can spawn more enemies 
  let spawnAmount = Math.floor(Math.random() * Game.level + 1);
  let en = [1, 2, 3];
    for(let i = 0; i < spawnAmount; i++) {
      //Spawn enemies
      Game.enemys.push(new Monster(en[Math.floor(Math.random() * en.length)], 0, 0, player));
    }
}


//The logic of game start sequence
//Game.init() => Game.createMap();
//Game.createMap() => Game.drawWholeMap();
//DrawWholeMap() => DrawRooms()
//This.drawRooms()
//this.levelSpawn() => this.spawnEnemies()
//this.spawnEnemies() => this.spawnStairs();
//this.spawnStairs => this.createSpawn();

//Initialize game

Game.init(); //Create display
player.draw();
Game.drawStatus();
console.log("ENTIRE GAME ENTITY ", Game.map);
```

**Monster Class**

```js
import { Game } from "../game.js";

/* New Monster class that represents any and all monsters we may spawn, will continue to get larger as we add more monsters
    Currently, monsters use an 'entity ID' system, where you call the id of the monster you're looking to spawn inside the
        constructor. This makes it easy to randomize the monster spawns and get unique sets of enemies each time 
            simply add monsters inside the switch statements, which determine movement type/speed. Eventually we should also adjust
                cone of influence for all monsters */

//Monster ID Keys
// 1 == kobold
// 2 == goblin
// 3 == witch

export class Monster {

    constructor(id, x, y, player) {
        this.id = id;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.px = 0;
        this.py = 0;
        this.sprite = "";
        this.health = 5; //We can change this to also maybe represent level? Still have to figure out levels
        this.path = [];
        this.player = player;
        this.astar = null;
        this.self = this;
        this.dmg = 2;
        this.name = "";
        this.color = ""

        switch(this.id) {
            //Change monster name dependant on ID provided
            case 1:
                this.name = "kobold";
                this.sprite = "k";
                this.color = "#F00";
            break;

            case 2:
                this.name = "goblin";
                this.sprite = "g";
                this.color = "#0F0";
            break;

            case 3: 
                this.name = "witch";
                this.sprite = "w";
                this.color = "#AF007F";
            break;


            //More as needed

        }

    }




act() {
    Game.engine.lock();

    if(this.health < 1) {
        // Char is dead, do no more
        let pos = this.x+","+this.y;
        let index = Game.enemys.indexOf(this);
        Game.map[pos] = "%";
        Game.scheduler.remove(this);
        Game.enemys.splice(index, 1); 
        Game.engine.unlock();
        return;
    }


    var passableCallback = function (x, y) { //This callback will return true if the positon exists within our game map
        //add portion that makes it so enemies cannot stand on-top of eachother, and will instead 'swarm'

        let pos = x+","+y;

        if(Game.map[pos]) {
            //If the game position exists in the map

            for(let i = 0; i < Game.enemys.length; i++) {
                //Loop through enemies, if the enemy does NOT equal the entity checking, it checks position with other enemies
                if(Game.enemys[i] != this.self) {
                    return(pos in Game.map);

                } else if(Game.enemys[i].x == x && Game.enemys[i].y == y)  {
                    return false;

                    }
                }
            }
        } 


    switch(this.id) { // Monster movement designation, you can change topology here
        case 1: //Is kobold, 4 topology
            this.astar = new ROT.Path.AStar(this.player.x, this.player.y, passableCallback, { topology: 4 });
        break;

        case 2: //is goblin, 8 topology
            this.astar = new ROT.Path.AStar(this.player.x, this.player.y, passableCallback, { topology: 8 });
        break;

        case 3: //Witch, 8 topology
            this.astar = new ROT.Path.AStar(this.player.x, this.player.y, passableCallback, { topology: 8});
        break;
        //More to come

    }




    var pathCallback =  (x, y) => {
        this.path.push([x, y]);
    }


    this.path = [];
    this.astar.compute(this.x, this.y, pathCallback);
    console.log("Astar computation complete");
    this.path.shift(); //Remove existing position

    if (this.path.length == 1) {
        //Attack player

        //Roll for attack
        let roll = Math.floor(ROT.RNG.getUniform() * 6);
        if(roll >= 3) {
            this.player.health -= this.dmg;
            Game.notifications.push("a " + this.name + " lunges at you! It connects dealing " + this.dmg +" damage\n\n");
            Game.notify(Game.notifications);
            Game.engine.unlock();
            this.draw();
            return;
        }else {
            Game.notifications.push("a " + this.name + " swings at you! But misses\n\n");
            Game.notify(Game.notifications);
            Game.engine.unlock();
            this.draw();
            return;
        }

    }

    if (this.path.length < 10) {
        let x = this.path[0][0];
        let y = this.path[0][1];

        // let pos = this.x + "," + this.y;
        // Game.map[pos] = ".";
        // this.x = x;
        // this.y = y;
        // pos = this.x + "," + this.y;
        // Game.map[pos] = this.sprite;

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.draw();
    }

    Game.engine.unlock();


}

draw() {
        Game.drawWholeMap();
    // Game.display.draw(this.x, this.y, this.sprite, this.color);
}

damage(amount, crit) { //I have started using a different naming convention here, where the first letter is the data-type. (iBloodLocation is an integer)
    this.health -= amount;
    let iBloodLocation = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1);
    let sBloodPos = "";
    let sBX = this.x += iBloodLocation;
    let sBY = this.y += iBloodLocation; 
    sBloodPos = sBX + "," + sBY;
    console.error("BLOOD POS ", sBloodPos);

    Game.map[sBloodPos] = ",";
    Game.drawWholeMap();
    if(crit) {
        //make arm

    }
}




}
```

**Player Class**

```js
import { Game } from "../game.js"
export class Player {
    event = (e) => this.handleEvent(e);

    constructor(x, y, art, inv, enemys) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.armor = 1;
        this.dmg = 1;
        this.sprite = art;
        this.health = 100;
        this.enemys = enemys;
        this.inventory = inv; //Array of objects with their own functions
    }


    act() {
        Game.engine.lock();
        window.addEventListener("keydown", this.event);
    }

    draw() {
        Game.drawWholeMap();
        //Game.display.draw(this.x, this.y, this.sprite, "#ff0");

    }

    equipItem(code) {
        let keyMap = {};
        keyMap[65] = "0";
        keyMap[66] = "1";
        keyMap[67] = "2";
        keyMap[68] = "3";
        keyMap[69] = "4";
        keyMap[70] = "5";

        //Player is wanting to do something with his inventory most likely
        let invItem = this.inventory[Number(keyMap[code])];

        //Time to re-write this to ensure that we also double check the equipped item slot to ensure you can't equip two items!

        if (!invItem.equipped) { //If item is not currently equipped

            for(let i = 0; i < this.inventory.length; i++) {

                if(this.inventory[i].slot == invItem.slot) {
                    if(this.inventory[i].equipped) {
                        this.inventory[i].equipped = false;
                        if(this.inventory[i].armor) this.armor -= this.inventory[i].armor;
                        if(this.inventory[i].dmg) this.dmg -= this.inventory[i].dmg;
                    }

                }
            }
            if (invItem.dmg) {
                this.dmg += invItem.dmg;
            }

            if (invItem.armor) {
                this.armor += invItem.armor
            }

            invItem.equipped = !invItem.equipped;
            Game.informPlayer(this.inventory);
            return;

        } else {

            if (invItem.dmg) {
                this.dmg -= invItem.dmg;
            }

            if (invItem.armor) {
                this.armor -= invItem.armor
            }

            invItem.equipped = !invItem.equipped;
            Game.informPlayer(this.inventory);
            return;
        }

    }

    handleEvent(e) {
        //Process the users input

        let keyMap = {};
        keyMap[38] = 0;
        keyMap[33] = 1;
        keyMap[39] = 2;
        keyMap[34] = 3;
        keyMap[40] = 4;
        keyMap[35] = 5;
        keyMap[37] = 6;
        keyMap[36] = 7;

        //Keys for item usage
        keyMap[65] = "0";
        keyMap[66] = "1";
        keyMap[67] = "2";
        keyMap[68] = "3";
        keyMap[69] = "4";
        keyMap[70] = "5";


        let code = e.keyCode;

        if (code == 76) this.look();



        if (code >= 65 && code < 70) {
            this.equipItem(code);
        }





        if(code == 190) { //Player is trying to go down stairs
            let pos = this.x+","+this.y;
            if(Game.map[pos] == ">") {
                //Player is standing on stairs, move them to a new dungeon, add 1 to level (depth)
                Game.level++;
                Game.resetGame();
            }
            return;
        }

        if (code == 73) {
            Game.informPlayer(this.inventory); // Read out inventory
        }

        if (code == 191) {//Player has hit question mark
            Game.informPlayer("Welcome to the help section! List of commands:\n \n Up Arrow: Move up \n Down Arrow: Move down \n Left Arrow: Move Left \n Right Arrow: Move right \n L: Pick up item \n I: Inventory");
        }


        if (!(code in keyMap)) { return; }


        let diff = ROT.DIRS[8][keyMap[code]];
        console.log(ROT.DIRS[8][keyMap[code]], " ROT DIRS KEY");
        let newX = this.x + diff[0];
        let newY = this.y + diff[1];

        let newKey = newX + "," + newY;

        // if (!(newKey in Game.map)) { return; } /* cannot move in this direction */

        if (!(newKey in Game.map)) { return; };

        console.log("Calculating if hit", this.enemys);
        //We've hit an enemy, let's figure out which one
        let parts = newKey.split(",");

        for (let i = 0; i < this.enemys.length; i++) {
            if (parts[0] == this.enemys[i].x && parts[1] == this.enemys[i].y) {
                //Roll a dice for fairness
                let roll = Math.floor(ROT.RNG.getUniform() * 6);
                if (roll >= 3) {
                    //Deduct damage from this entity
                    Game.notifications.push("You swing at the " + this.enemys[i].name + " and hit! Dealing " + this.dmg + " damage");
                    Game.notify(Game.notifications);
                    //this.enemys[i].health -= this.dmg;
                    this.enemys[i].damage(this.dmg, false);
                    Game.engine.unlock();
                    return;
                } else {
                    Game.notifications.push("You swing at the " + this.enemys[i].name + " and miss!");
                    Game.notify(Game.notifications);
                    Game.engine.unlock();
                    return;

                }

            }
        }

        console.log("Current NewX values ", newX, newY);

        Game.display.draw(this.x, this.y, Game.map[this.x + "," + this.y]);
        this.x = newX;
        this.y = newY;
        this.draw();
        window.removeEventListener("keydown", this.event);
        Game.engine.unlock();
    }


    look() {
        //Method for checking the ground for items, picking up loose items, looting corpses, chests, etc.
        //Here we'll define some stuff for making sure that corpses are removed (Or changed to a different look?)

        let pos = this.x + "," + this.y; //Players position turned into a string, for use in Game.map[]

        switch(Game.map[pos]) {
            //Switch because it becomes an ez jump table, incase we have lots of looting options

            case "%":
                //Is corpse
                //Do we get loot? Let's roll a dice for this
                let roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
                if(roll >= 3) {
                    let loot = Game.loot[Math.floor(Math.random() * Game.loot.length)];
                    Game.informPlayer("You picked up " + loot.name);
                    this.inventory.push(loot);
                    Game.map[pos] = ".";
                } else {
                    Game.informPlayer("You found nothing when looking the corpse..");
                    Game.map[pos] = ".";
                }

            break;

            case "*":
                //Loot box
                let loot = Game.loot[Math.floor(Math.random() * Game.loot.length)];
                Game.informPlayer("You picked up " + loot.name);
                this.inventory.push(loot);
                Game.map[pos] = ".";
            break;



        }

    }







}
```

I know there's quite a bit here, and it's probably mostly a mess that isn't quite understandable -- I appreciate all of your guys time in order to steer me in the right directions

Should I be using Inheritance? Like, if something is moveable it should have a moveable class? It feels like I'd have a class for everything in this way, one for attacking or looking or speaking

Or am I thinking about this wrong?